# Qt Cannot add a new Kit for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, qt, homebrew

I am trying to set up Qt for iPhone Development. I have added a new kit with device type `iOS Simulator` Device `iOS Simulator (default for iOS Simulator)` with C compiler `iphonesimulator-clang` and C++ compiler `iphonesimulator-clang ++`. I am getting an Error icon showing the following error.

> iphonesimulator-clang++ (x86-darwin-generic-mach_o-32bit) can not produce code for Qt version "Qt 5.9.2 (5.9.2)" (x86-darwin-generic-mach_o-64bit)

I have installed Qt through brew. I can see it looks like brew have installed Qt 5.9.2 64 bit only. But the selected compiler is of 32 but. I think that is the reason. Am I correct ? So how can I install Qt 5.9.2 32 bit with brew ? if the reason is something different then how can I solve that ?

It will be difficult for me to uninstall qt now. Because I have PyQT and VTK and don't know what else dependent on Qt.

Comment: how does things appear at Xcode side?

Comment: I don't know anything about objective C or swift but I can create an example iphone application build it and run it in its own simulator

Comment: forget about swift ..etc. your simulator should also exist in Xcode .. and Qt _automatically_ sets compiler and simulator based existing on Xcode

Comment: Yes I can see all the simulators and start them from Qt CReator. I think this is what you are asking https://imgur.com/a/SOyCz

Comment: And this is the error I am talking about https://imgur.com/a/qsw1K My configuration screenshot is on https://imgur.com/a/jmJUk

Comment: you are looking under device ist, but first check those: https://imgur.com/a/P7xia , https://imgur.com/a/nrSea , https://imgur.com/a/BMKpc

Comment: my point: if your Xcode has clang 64 and it should , then it should be ok and work!! _unless you didn't build such simulator in Xcode_

Comment: It have the compiler and I think it's not complaining about the compiler it's complaining about architecture mismatch of qt libraries and compiler architecture

Comment: sorry that's not possible for auto detected kits. a detected kit should have compatible  architecture , if you look at "compilers" snip .. and chec k the ABI, its same as yours: **_x86-darwin-generic-mach_o-32bit_**, so what I suspect is the simulator for your architecture is not build in Xcode

Comment: No kit was auto detected. I added them manually. Qt 5.9.2 ABI is 64 bit. and in Compilers Tab I see `iphonesimulator-clang++` ABI is 32 bit. But what is expected ? Should Qt have 32 bit ABI ? or Should the compiler have 64 bit ABI ? or Both of them should have both ABIs ? which one is normal ?

Comment: I know, and this is a bad sign! why Qt is unable to auto detect your Xcode settings and generate the kit .. I have been telling all the time something could be incorrect at Xcode side

Comment: BTW my qt is also clang64 .. same as yours .. the ABI was automatically generated .. my point is I am afraid even if you install what you call Qt 32 ..you end up with same trouble

Comment: So your iphonesimulator compiler is 64 then ?

Comment: actually yes, my Qt in clang 64, If you notice the compiler snip Xcode has both 32/64

Comment: I tried cloning `iphonesimulator-clang` and `iphonesimulator-clang++` and change their ABI to 64 bit (codegen and linker flag is still i386). Now the error is gone but it shows an warning `Device Type is not supported`. Device Type is `iOS Simulator`

Comment: good, you better delete the device and recreate it

Comment: Delete Button is disabled on Devices Tab. But I don't remember creating that. It is iOS Simulator (default for iOS Simulator). And the error complains about `Device Type` not the device.

Comment: try restart Qt. my final comment if you end up with bad setup try online installer